# node.js - using eventemitter throughout a project

Tags: events, node.js, eventemitter

just wondering what the best approach is for using eventemitter throughout multiple exports without the modules becoming too coupled with each other.

for instance i have module foo which deals with requests, now to break up the code I have a separate module (bar) which performs an action when a specific request comes in. I want to use an eventemitter for this.

any help is appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to use it across different modules you either send it as a function param everywhere or set it as a global variable (not recommended).